# How to get a complex value in array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is my JSON array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [active] => Y
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sub] => 5
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

My question how can I get value `5` in `sub` by using `foreach`.

Comment: what is `$results`?? where is `data` and `type`??

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: For future reference, it helps if the data you show us matches the code you show us. Then you dont get lots of questions asking why the 2 dont seem to match in any way. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You have to explain better what you want and what is your problem and what is the expected result.

Comment: Use stack snippets when you have code that can be run in the browser, if you have other code use 4 space indent or `{}` button.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one `[sub]` in the data structure? If so do you want all of them?

Comment: Do you know it will always be there? Or do you need to check it first

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($rs_amount as $result) {
    foreach ($result['sub_resource'] as $sub_resource) {
        foreach ($sub_resource as $subs) {
            echo $subs['sub'] . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
foreach($results['data'] as $result) {
      if(is_array($result)) {
           print_r($result) ;
           echo '<br>';
      } else {
           echo $result['type'] . '<br>';
      }   
}
```

Comment: Would it not then just be simpler to do `print_r($results['data']);` and cut out all the foreach loop completely